# Landscape page, PDF section title float

Tags: floats, pdf, landscape

So here's my problem:
I have a page in my thesis report which is in landscape orientation.
A PDF file is on this page. This page also needs a (section) title. However this title is floating somewhere on the left of the page, in the middle (see figure). I'm out of options, Could u help me?

here's my code:

```
\newpage
\afterpage{%
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
    \section{Planning}
    \begin{figure}[b] \centering
    \includepdf[pages=-, scale=0.9, angle =90]{badatlatex.pdf}
    \end{figure}
\end{landscape}
```

Heres an image of the problem:

[image: latex baddie]

I want the planning section title to be in the top Left, above the PDF file. I dont know how it got where it is now.. On other pages it doesn't float like this.

UPDATE
This:

```
\newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{landscape}% Landscape page
    \begin{figure}[t!]
    \section{Planning}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[b!] \centering
    \includepdf[pages=-, scale=0.9, angle =90]{afstudeerproces.pdf}
    \end{figure}
\end{landscape}
```

doesn't work, it actually lowers the title..

UPDATE 2:
I guess i worked around it, rotating the pdf file (angle = 90) and removed the landscape page.

Cheers and thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why `afterpage`?

Comment: I dont know, it doesn't do anything or change anything when i remove it. I coppied the landscaping code from somewhere on the internet, it must have been there also.