# How to add section title and inserted PDF at same page?

Tags: pdfpages

in the appendix of my report, I want to include a pdf file in landscape format. The issue I have right now is that I don't manage to get the title at the same page as the included pdf (the table).

This is the code I use:

```
\appendix
\newpage
\section{Gantt Chart}
\includepdf[pages={-},fitpaper,rotateoversize, picturecommand*={%
     \put(75,760){%
         \parbox{\textwidth}{\section{Gantt Chart}\label{app:Gantt Chart}}
     }}]{Gannt_chart.pdf}
```

The code from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269291/landscape-page-pdf-section-title-float) works partially: I get the title and pdf at the same page, but in portrait mode only.

[image: screenshot of problem]

Comment: Do you want the page in portrait or landscape format?

Comment: landscape, just like the screenshot I attached, but with the title on top of it instead on one page before like now.